# Yandex-map-api 3.0. Как отключить удаление меток выходящих за пределы видимости?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Когда метка оказывается рядом с границей контейнера, она исчезает. API удаляет её и доступа напрямую к ней нет.
Возможно ли отключить эту функцию?

Comment: Приводите пример кода, чтобы можно было понять, что и где сделано не так, как надо. Посмотрите тестовую карту с целой пачкой меток, ни одна из которых не желает исчезать: https://jsbin.com/kelariy/1/edit?js,output